# Method ambiguous in a hierarchy of two generic classes while method actually given same-type argument

Tags: java, generics

Why method f() is ambiguous in Derived?

```
class Base<T> {
    void f(T arg) { }
}

class Derived<S extends CharSequence> extends Base<String> {
    void f(S arg) { }  // compiles OK so far !!!
}

    Derived<String> obj = new Derived<>();
    obj.f("hi"); // c.ERR: The method f(String) is ambiguous for the type Derived<String>
```

BUT:

```
Derived<StringBuffer> obj = new Derived<>();
obj.f("hi"); // OK! Overloaded methods resolved?
obj.f(new StringBuffer()); // OK! Overloaded methods resolved?
```

`void f(String)` is inherited from *Base* (`void f(Object) at runtime`), same `void f(String)` is generated in *Derived* (`void f(Object)` at runtime).

Please help me to pinpoint when and where is the conflict?

So far I tend to think that proper method to call is chosen from all possible overloaded methods at compile-time only (!), and Derived extends Base means to the compiler that at compile-time Derived has two methods with same signatures: Base.f(String) and Derived.f(String) which makes f("hi") call ambiguous (both overloaded versions apply).

Overriding in this case is not possible (@Override in Derived really gives compile error) because same signature (same argument) cannot be guaranteed, and it is just one lucky coincidence for ...extends Base where override could be possible, but JLS would flag compile error.

The fact that real runtime signatures of methods (as seen by JVM after compilation) are `void Base.f(Object)` and `void f(CharSequence)` is totally irrelevant to overload resolution because that resolution happens only at compile time!

Java Language Specification:

> When a method is invoked (§15.12), the number of actual arguments (and
> any explicit type arguments) and the **compile-time types of the
> arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the
> method that will be invoked** (§15.12.2). If the method that is to be
> invoked is an instance method, the actual method to be invoked will be
> determined at run time, using dynamic method lookup (§15.12.4).

P.S. Are Base.f() and Derived.f() always overloaded? But how then? As `void f(Object) at runtime` vs `void f(CharSequence) at runtime`? If they are overridden in case of new Derived, then are they overloaded or overridden depending on what type parameter Derived given during instantiation? Is that possible?

Comment: There's no guarantee that `S` is `String`

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the class `Base` means that method `f()` can accept parameters of any type. It can be not only String, but also Integer, Long, and actually an instance of any class. What class, it depends on generic parameter used when an instance of class `Base` is created.

The definition of the class `Derived` allows to pass instances of any sub-classes of `CharSequence`.

It is very important that the definition of `Derived` does not mean that its generic parameter `S` is somehow related to the generic parameter `T` of the parent class. Such definition means, that the method `f()` in `Derived` does not override method `f()` from the parent class. Thus, the compiler sees two methods.

What could you do? It depends on what is your goal. But one solution may be following:

```
class Base<T> {
    void f(T arg) { }
}

class Derived<S extends CharSequence> extends Base<S> {
    void f(S arg) { }
}

Derived<String> obj = new Derived<>();
obj.f("hi");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given case of `Base` class,

```
class Base<T> {
  void f(T arg) { }
}
```

Your `Derived` class,

```
class Derived<S extends CharSequence> extends Base<String> {
  void f(S arg) { } 
}
```

doesn't override the `f()` method, but rather overloads the `f()` method because of type erasure.

Hence, the `Derived` class contains 2 overloads of `f()`,

- one from the parent `Base` class: `void f(Object arg)`
- another from its own class: `void f(CharSequence arg)`

Since, in java *Generics* provide only *compilte-time type safety*, compiler makes full use of this to infer correct overload of `f()` on a parameterized `Derived<SomeSubClassOfCharSequence>` depending on the argument passed.

This is what happened in the case of

```
Derived<StringBuffer> obj = new Derived<>();
obj.f("hi"); // OK! Overloaded methods resolved?
obj.f(new StringBuffer()); // OK! Overloaded methods resolved?
```

But, in the case of

```
Derived<String> obj = new Derived<>();
obj.f("hi");
```

The compiler is not able to infer the one overload over the other, hence the ambiguity.

To answer yourquestions:

1. Are Base.f() and Derived.f() always overloaded?: This depends on whether the type-erasured result of these declared versions of `f()` produce different method signatures.
2. There are scenarios in which compiler itself generates a new override of the type-erasured `Base.f()` in the Derived.f() method, aka *bridge methods*. But your case is not one of these scenarios.